# Saving form state after a page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, cookies

I have a list of checkboxes.

If the page is refreshed before the user submits the form, I want the state of the checkboxes (checked or not checked) to be preserved.

Ie: user selects option 1, option 4 and option 5. The page refreshes and option 1, option 4 and option 5 remain checked.

I have looked into serialising then storing a cookie but I just cant wrap my head around it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is causing the page to refresh without it being submitted? Is this part not under your control perhaps?

Comment: What is your server-side language? I think the easiest way would be to do AJAX calls to store the data in sessions (don't make cookies unless you have to).

Comment: This is a controlled refresh for aesthetic purposes Java Drinker. If a checkbox is checked then a css class is applied to the parent <li>

I am using php Kerry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store data in cookies (you could use [jquery.cookies.js](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/)) when user select option

```
$('#select_element').change(function() {
  $.cookies.set('check_box', $(this).val());
});
```

and when you load page put data in check box

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ((check = $.cookies.get('check_box')) != '') {
     $('#select_element').val(check);
  }
});
```

But I not test it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion jcubic. I've just tried your code but it doesn't seem to work. I wonder if I'm doing it wrong? I simply created:

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#porchia').change(function() {
  $.cookies.set('check_box', $(this).val());
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ((check = $.cookies.get('check_box')) != '') {
     $('#porchia').val(check);
  }
});
</script>

The IDs linked to the checkbox. I checked the checkbox, then hit F5 to refresh the page and the check disappeared.

Comment: Sorry this code only work with options form tags, if you want to use checkboxes use this:
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.cookies.get('check_box')) {
    $('#check_box').attr('checked', 'true');
  } else {
    $('#check_box').removeAttr('checked');
  }
  $('#check_box').click(function() {
     $.cookies.set('check_box', $(this).attr('checked'));
  });
});
and html <input type="checkbox" id="check_box" checked="true">

Answer (score 1):

If all your visitors happen to use modern browsers then you can use sessionStorage.

Session storage works like a JavaScript object that persists between requests for as long as the window remains (or until you delete the data manually). Javascript example:

```
sessionStorage.varName = 3;.
```

It works in at least Chrome, Firefox and Safari.